# i am making an comment section in php under my file upload

Tags: php, html

```
      $query_file="SELECT * FROM files";
      $result_file = mysql_query($query_file);
          if ($result_file) {
          while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result_file))
           {
           if($row[file_type] == "image"){
           echo" <image src=".$row['file_location']."width=340 height=240>"; 
       echo "</image><br>";
       echo "</br>";
       echo $row['file_description'];
       echo "</br>";
       }
         if (isset($_POST['post_comment']) and !empty($_POST['write_comment'])) {
           $comment_description = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['write_comment'])))); {
             if (!$file_id=mysql_query("SELECT file_id FROM files WHERE file_id='$id' ")) {
                    echo 'Invalid file ID';
              } else {  
               $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('','$user','$fileid',NOW(),'$comment_description')");
                 }
         }
    }
                 echo "
                  <div style='float: left; width: 100%;''>
                 <form action='' method='post'>
                  <textarea name='write_comment' rows='3' cols='50' style='float: left;'></textarea>
                  <input type='submit' name='post_comment' id='' value='Comment' style='height: 40kpx; float: left;''d>
                 </form>
                  </div>
                  ";
      }
     }
      else{
      echo mysql_error();
     }
```

this is my code for making comment section  but it is not aking the particular fileid which i have uploaded 
how should i correct it
and my sql table for commment...

```
comments_id,comment_by,comment_on,comment_date,comment_description
```

and my files table

(`id`, `file_title`, `file_description`, `file_keywords`, `privacy`, `uploaded_by`, `date_uploaded`, `md5`, `views`, `file_id`, `file_md5`, `file_location`, `file_type`)

Comment: you are using the deprecated `mysql` api and your code is vulnerable to sql injection. `image`? the tag should be `img` and is self-closing

Comment: The code above has mistakes. Where is `$id` defined? Where is `$fileid` defined? Where is `$user` defined? lots of errors

Comment: in file i have made an type which make it to fetch the data in one page and i will change it ito sqli but tell me the method ause i am facing the prblem since many days how should i defined the function

Comment: there are many errors - it is hard to know where to start or what the real problem is. You cannot get the file id for a file until it is uploaded though

Comment: should i send you the codes

Comment: update your question with your actual code if the above is not the real code you are using

Comment: the above codes are real

Comment: You have errors in there - several and you have not answered previous questions about where $id,$fileid etc are defined

Comment: Is the problem that you wish to add a FORM, under the image, that allows you to add a comment for each particular image?

Comment: can i mail you the  codes

Comment: yes i want like that if any1 upload an file(image/video) then the comment box shold be there

Comment: no - I do not want you to email any code thankyou! ` an file 90`??? what?

Comment: an file 90???? ????

Comment: you edited last comment after I posted - you had typed `an file 90` but have now changed it .. I think I am beginning to understand what it is you are asking

Comment: that was misprint

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of the original code and the lack of clarity on what the actual question is the following may or may not be what you were trying to do.

There were **many** errors in the original code - some of them PHP, the others basic HTML faults. I tried to identify and fix them though I make no guarantees they are all fixed.

The form that allows the user to add a comment has a hidden field that contains the ID for the image. That ID is POSTed along with the comment and is inserted using the code at the top ~ but again - where is `$user` defined?

The code here is vulnerable to sql injection but as you have stated you are going to change this to `mysqli` then that is irrelevant perhaps.

```
<?php
    /*
        This handles the insertion of the comment
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['write_comment'], $_POST['post_comment'], $_POST['file_id'] ) ){

        $fileid=$_POST['file_id'];
        $comment=$_POST['write_comment'];
        $user='GERONIMO';   /* WHERE IS $user DEFINED????? */

        $query=mysql_query( "INSERT INTO comments VALUES ( '', '$user', '$fileid', NOW(), '$comment_description' )" );
    }
?>



<?php

    /*
        This is to display the image and
        the form so that a user can add a
        comment
    */

    $sql='SELECT * FROM files';
    $result = mysql_query( $sql );

    if ( $result ) {
        while( $row= mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {

            if( $row['file_type'] == "image" ){

                echo "
                <div style='float:left; width:100%;'>
                    <img src='{$row['file_location']}' width=340 height=240 />
                    <p>
                    {$row['file_description']}
                    </p>
                    <form method='post'>
                        <textarea name='write_comment' rows='3' cols='50' style='float:left;'></textarea>
                        <input type='hidden' name='file_id' value='{$row['file_id']}' />
                        <input type='submit' name='post_comment' value='Comment' style='height:40px; float:left;'>
                    </form>
                </div>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: i have used as like this previously but on that time only one data is adding in table not for the particular file

Comment: can i mail you the code pls help me in code coz now its frautating to study php coz every time error error so plss

Comment: create a pastebin paste and share the link